# Compiling Error with LINQ Sorting Code Using List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

Compilation Error:
"The name 'b' does not exist in the current context"

Code:

```
    List<PositionValues> list = new List<PositionValues>();
    PositionValues item1 = new PositionValues();
    item1.Position = 2;
    item1.Value = 44;
    list.Add(item1);

    PositionValues item2 = new PositionValues();
    item2.Position = 1;
    item2.Value = 33;
    list.Add(item2);


    PositionValues item3 = new PositionValues();
    item3.Position = 1;
    item3.Value = 22;
    list.Add(item3);


    var resultList = from b in list 
                     group b by b.Position into g 
                     orderby b.Value select b;
```

The above code relies on this struct:

```
public struct PositionValues
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The position.
    /// </summary>
    public int Position;

    /// <summary>
    /// The position.
    /// </summary>
    public double Value;
}
```

I am hoping to get the following sort order:

```
resultList[0] {1, 22}
resultList[1] {1, 33}
resultList[2] {2, 44}
```

"Position" is first in the parenthesis and "Value" is second.

Comment: Once you've grouped, you've got *groups*, not individual items - so it doesn't make any sense to order the group by a single individual item value. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve (nor why you're using mutable structs...)

Comment: Jon - thanks for the question. My priority was getting the items ordered in that specified.

Comment: Do you mean within each group? What if you had a {2, 35} value?

Comment: Thanks Jon. That would be between resultList[1] and resultList[2] as currently shown. I see your case as covered by the ordering of resultList[0] and resultList[1] but perhaps I am missing something. Any ideas on how to make this an in place sort if needed? In certain cases it would be more efficient (i.e. no ToList() needed for conversion).

Comment: Hang on, re-reading, it's not clear that you want them grouped *at all*. Your result is just three positions - no grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the expected result you posted, you don't need to use `group by`.

What you want is more something like this:

```
var result = list.OrderBy(x => x.Position).ThenBy(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: If you have any ideas on sorting in place without using ToList() that would be great (for efficiency/an alternative). Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you want the query style,

```
var query =
    from b in list
    orderby b.Position, b.Value
    select b;
```

Comment: This was as good as the first response, but could only mark one as the answer. Thanks very much. This is a great alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You've used `b` into a group `g`, so now use `g`. You must also orderby b before grouping into g.

```
var resultList = from b in list orderby b.Value group b by b.Position into g select g;
```